# Use tex subfile as appendix with separate TOC and frontpage

Tags: table-of-contents, subfiles

I have two files that are very similar; their preambles are very similar. They are also both full documents with their own chapters, front pages and tables of content. I want to use one of those files, let's say `MAIN.tex` as a main document, and the other one, let's say `ADDITION.tex` as an appendix.

I am currently using the `subfiles` package to make this work, and it works okay, but there are two things I want to change:

- In the table of contents of the main document, it lists chapters as `1 a, 2 b, 3 c, etc`, and after `\appendix` goes on to `A x, B y, C z`. Instead, I want it to say `1 a, 2 b, 3 c, A. DocumentName`.
- Currently, the `ADDITION.tex` section doesn't have a table of contents at all. I want the chapters of this document to show up as in a regular document; 1. Introduction; 2. Research; etc.

Is it possible to implement it this way? I also fiddled around a bit with the `standalone` package, but it didn't do much for me. Below are, for context, the main bits of the relevant files.

**MAIN.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

\input{_support/preamble}

\begin{document}

\input{_support/titlepage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\input{chapters/00_introduction}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Problem statement}
\input{chapters/1_problemstatement}

\chapter{Deliverables}
\input{chapters/2_deliverables}

\chapter{Requirements}
\input{chapters/3_requirements}

\chapter{Design}
\input{chapters/4_design}

\chapter{Quality Assurance}
\input{chapters/5_qualityassurance}

\chapter{Client Involvement}
\input{chapters/6_clientinvolvement}

\chapter{Project management}
\input{chapters/7_projectmanagement}

\subfile{addition/ADDITION}

\end{document}
```

**ADDITION.tex**

```
\documentclass[../MAIN.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}

\appendix

\input{ADDITION/__support/titlepage}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

\input{ADDITION/arch_chapters/00_introduction}

\tableofcontents

\input{ADDITION/arch_chapters/05_assumptions}
\input{ADDITION/arch_chapters/10_system_scope}
\input{ADDITION/arch_chapters/20_environment}
\input{ADDITION/arch_chapters/30_design}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately nobody can reproduce your observation from the code you posted, as many files are missing. Perhaps you can simplify the code a little more, so it's self-contained? // Not sure if you look for multiaudience https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multiaudience , where you can create content for different audiences from one file via flags?

Comment: To me, it seems you want to have `ADDITION.tex` as an independent paper in the appendix of `MAIN.tex`. In this case, I'd typeset `ADDITION` standalone and then either include it with the package `pdfpages` or typeset `MAIN` as well and then join the two PDFs with any suitable external program. This has the advantage that the two papers cannot interfere with each other, and the paper in the appendix is a copy of the original